# How to specify dial code in code using Twilio

Tags: twilio

I am currently developing a phone system using Twilio and want to set the dial code for GB automatically in my code without the user having to specify +44 and removing the 0 from the number when dialing out using Twilio

Comment: What code do you have already? It's hard to help without a base of what you've tried.

Comment: Hi phil thanks for responding i am currently using C#

Comment: Sorry, I mean what have you tried to accomplish this so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In its simplest form it will be something like the below. May need to expand on this if you are likely to make international calls.

```
//presuming your twilio callback is providing a To number in the request
if(To.startsWith("0"))
{
    To = To.Replace("0", "+44")
}
```